# How to import openData text in my leaflet map

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, leaflet, opendata

I am a bit ashamed with the problem I am currently encountering but I don't understand how to load OpenData from this portal ([Toulouse Open Data](https://data.toulouse-metropole.fr/explore/dataset/recensement-population-2012-grands-quartiers-logement/api/)) which returns a json with a rather [original architecture](https://data.toulouse-metropole.fr/api/v2/catalog/datasets/recensement-population-2012-grands-quartiers-logement/records?rows=100&pretty=false&timezone=UTC) ...

My code which send the request is like that :

```
var myXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
myXHR.open('GET', 'https://data.toulouse-metropole.fr/api/v2/catalog/datasets/recensement-population-2012-grands-quartiers-logement/records?rows=100&pretty=false&timezone=UTC');
myXHR.send(null);

myXHR.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
    console.log(e.loaded + ' / ' + e.total);
});

myXHR.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if (myXHR.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (myXHR.status === 200) {
            var myResponse = JSON.parse(myXHR.responseText);
            console.log("myXHR", myResponse);
        } else {
            console.log("myXHR", myXHR.statusText);
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help ! =)

Comment: You should have at least recorded and posted the data structure, typically what is provided in the first page you link to.

Comment: Hi Ghybs, I didn't understood what you asked ... if you need see the data structure, you can click on the second link ! :)